# escape &amp in shell script

Tags: escaping

I am trying to replace the string in select statement through shell script. when I run the script I am getting 'amp: command not found'

fragment of the sql is 'replace(p.title,'&amp','&')

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your single-quotes to double-quotes to stop the shell from trying to evaluate the string.